# No context menu is shown for child of expandable listview

Tags: android, contextmenu, expandablelistview

I'm having an expandable listview in my activity. I want to show a contextmenu for the childs. Basically I know how to do this, but when implementing the contextmenu it never shows up for the child views. Just for long clicks on the group view and I didn't find the reason for this behavior. Any ideas maybe?
Thanks in advance!

Setting up the expandable listview:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listed_data, container, false);
    parser = new SvwXmlparser("a", getSherlockActivity());
    elv = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.svwexplist);
    return v;


}
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    registerForContextMenu(elv);
    infos = parser.parse();
    showData();
}
public void showData()
{
    adapter = new SvwInfoAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), infos);
    elv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) {
    return children.get(groupPos).get(childPos);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) {
    return childPos;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //TODO:modify
    String player = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
     if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.svw_team_child_layout, null);
        }
     convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
     TextView players = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvteamChild);
     /*if(childPosition> 1)
     {
         players.setText((childPosition-1) + ". " + player);
     }
     else
     {
         players.setText(player);
     }*/
     players.setText(player);
    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) {
    return children.get(groupPos).size();
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return true;
}
```

Create Contextmenu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition);
    int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition);
    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    Toast toas =Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), groupPos + " - " + childPos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toas.show();
```

The toast shows for every group but not for the children...

Comment: I don't think I see anything here that would cause trouble. It may be worth trying without the `setFocusableInTouchMode` call. Also, I don't think the xml portion is relevant. Could you show where you create and set up the ExpandableListView? Do you set a long click handler?

Comment: I just register for the context menu. And I tried it before without the setFocusableInTouchMode, that doesn't make any different. I adjusted the code snippets above.

Comment: I just added your code to one of my ExpandableListViews and it works ok. I get the toast for both groups and children, and otherwise they behave normally. It may have to do with your list's choice mode -- I did have to remove my call to `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);`. Otherwise, maybe it's related to sherlock? Maybe sherlock sets up a contextual action bar automatically or something?

Comment: I didn't set a certain choice mode, but tried no every option. No result. I also looked into the context menu example of the sherlock package, seem to be same as my code. And last I tried it with a new layout file, still no difference. :-/

Comment: I'm stumped. You might try removing Sherlock and the compatibility library (which I guess you're also using) and try to isolate one of those as the culprit. There is a bug [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20065) that is not your problem, but might be related. It isn't the real solution, but you can probably make it work by setting an onLongClickListener on the child views and using `getActivity().openContextMenu(elv)`.

Comment: I'm going nuts... I copied the code into a new project and tried to start it both as Activity and ExpandableListActivity. Still no change. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out... It's not working to set touchable=false in the xml. After calling setTouchable(false) in the adapter's getView-methods for group and child view, everything is working as supposed.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I could not find setTouchable method. Could you please elaborate on your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. The above solution didn't work out for me. And I found a simple solution!

This is what helped me:

In my ExpandableListAdapter in the method:

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View concertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ... 
    concertView.setLongClickable( true);
```